# How safe is it to show php serialized data arrays as values in a JSON API?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, serialization, advanced-custom-fields

I have a client which uses the WP REST API, an older developer has added several points of meta data available for the public through the REST API. The data contains important meta keys and several serialized data arrays, but none are serialized php objects.

I quickly became alarmed that this might be a potential security risk for our clients site.

Would you consider this a security risk? If yes, what kind of attacks does this open up for?

Edit:
This article (http://v2.wp-api.org/guide/problems/) states that:

- **Serialized data can expose private data**
- **Serialized data has security problems**

More on: **Serialized data has security problems**

> Allowing serialized data allows input of any custom object, which causes the object to be created on the server. This is essentially a Remote Code Execution vulnerability, one of the worst classes of security bug.

Does serialized arrays also fit into this quote? Or is it only serialized objects that is the main security risk?

Edit 2:
I think its this plugin, and not the WP REST API which is used:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

Though both plugin exists in the WordPress installation. It seems like the WP REST API does not allow any serialized data at all.

Comment: You basically ask in what way the publication of data reveals that data. Such question does not make too much sense, does it?

Comment: Well, I ask people if they consider using serialized data arrays in a public api could be a security risk. English is not my primary language. But I do think that such a question makes sense. But it might be a badly formulated question...

Comment: The way _how_ data is published does not make any difference. The question is if it is published or not. If that API publishes _additional_ data, meant only for internal purposes, so which is _not_ published otherwise, then yes, this _might_ show up additional attack vectors. But note that a CMS typically publishes post IDs and the like anyway and that is _not_ a security risk at all. You should however keep in mind that _any_ page build using wordpress has to be considered insecure.

Comment: I do not consider the posting of page IDs to be a problem, though I do not like that the api is showing internal meta keys for the public.